# How to force an event callback to wait until async call is resolved?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, dom-events

I have a form that listens to an event called `onBeforeSubmit`. This event is fired when I submit a form, but will stop the submission if the callback returns `false`.

### Problem

My callback involves an async call to an API. How do I force the event to wait for the promise to resolve before deciding to return false or not? Currently it doesn't wait for the `fetch()` to resolve - I've tried both `async/await` and `.then()` approaches...

#### What I tried:

Attempt 1:

```js
onBeforeSubmit: async (e) {
  const res = await fetch(url);
  // if res value fails some condition
  return false
}
```

Attempt 2:

```js
onBeforeSubmit: (e) {
  fetch(url).then( res => {
  // if res value fails some condition
  return false
  })
}
```

Shouldn't the `await` force javascript to wait until the fetch resolves before moving on to the next line?

I also noticed that whenever I put the `async` keyword, it ignores the `return false` statement and goes ahead with the submission anyways. What's causing that?

EDIT: This is a 3rd party API, so I can't control how onBeforeSubmit behaves :(

Comment: No, `async` always returns a promise. To access `false`, the caller would need to await promise resolution. Could you provide a little bit more context and maybe embellish the example a bit--is the function that receives the `return false` value under your control?

Comment: What makes you think that your code isn't waiting for the promise returned by fetch to resolve?

Comment: Hi @ggorlen, thanks for the response - unfortunately, it's from a 3rd party API so I don't have control over it. I was hoping to find a way to make it accept promises.

Comment: @NickParsons Currently the form gets submitted even with the `return` statement inside the `.then`. As I understood it, the wrapping function only returns inside the `.then`. Seems like I misunderstood it though.

Comment: That's probably because the promise is treated at truthy by the caller: `console.log(!!new Promise(res => res))` prints true.

Comment: @ggorlen Ahh, that makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an event handler that is expecting a synchronous return value, but you're trying to run an asynchronous operation in that callback.  That just won't work in Javascript.

When you run the asynchronous function, your callback function returns immediately at that point and the asynchronous function finishes in its own callback.  If you mark the callback `async`, that just means that it immediately returns a promise.  Since the `onBeforeSubmit` event handler is expecting a boolean to be returned, not a promise, it doesn't work properly.

There is no way in Javascript to make this callback "wait" so it can synchronous return a boolean.

The usual way around this is to always return `false` so the form is not automatically submitted.  Then, run your asynchronous operation and if it succeeds, then you manually submit the form (without further validation) from within that asynchronous completion callback.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I suspected this was the case. Thank you for the workaround suggestion, it seems feasible. I'll try that and check back!

Comment: @micronyks - Given that the OP is using a callback from a framework that expects a boolean to be returned synchronously, what is wrong about this explanation?  It seems more like it's you that don't understand the actual problem here.  There is no way to get a synchronously returned boolean from an asynchronous operation in Javascript.

Comment: you don't know the usage of the `async await` and how it works. Learn it first. Your first statement itself is wrong.....

Comment: @micronyks - You're missing the basic concept that some code in the framework that the OP is using is expecting a SYNCHRONOUS boolean to be returned from a function.  That's what the OP needs.  No amount of `await` is going to offer that.  Also, note the edit the OP added to their question that `This is a 3rd party API, so I can't control how onBeforeSubmit behaves`.

Comment: `also noticed that whenever I put the async keyword, it ignores the return false statement and goes ahead with the submission anyways. What's causing that?` check this statement.  Ok never mind. Let him decide, if he thinks your answer is correct, I can't do anything. Let him give you points for wrong explanation by accepting your answer... I provided you a demo to prove myself. Your first statement is completely wrong and misleading. `async await` means to make process synchronous and demo proves it.....

Comment: @micronyks - That's where you're misunderstanding `await` and misunderstanding the constraints the OP is working under.  It does not make the process synchronous.  It does not allow you to synchronously return a boolean (which is what the API the OP uses expects).  `await` suspends the internal execution of one function and then that function immediately returns a promise at that point (not a boolean).  I'm not going to argue this further with you.

Comment: @jfriend00 So I tried your workaround, it almost works...But when I use js to manually submit the form from the callback, js fires the `onBeforeSubmit` event _again_, so it runs in an infinite loop. Next, I'm going to try to remove that event listener before programatically submitting.

Comment: @thk_ - Yes, you will probably need to set a flag somewhere (probably a property on some object) that your code in `onBeforeSubmit` checks so it can just return `true` when you've already completed validation.  As I said in my answer, you need it to skip the `onBeforeSumbit()` logic when you've already completed the validation and are submitting it manually.  Or, you have to do the manual submission in a way that doesn't go through your framework and thus won't trigger `onBeforeSubmit`.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest, to use `event.preventDefault()` to stop the form from been submitted and  then make your `fetch` request, if the response value is false the form was not submitted in the first place, else you remove the form's  event listener onsubmit and then you add a new event listener to submit the form

Here is an example of what your code should look like

```
var submitform=function sbmform(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  fetchvalue()
}
const form = document.getElementById('myform')
form.addEventListener('submit',submitform,false)

async function fetchvalue(){
  const res = await fetch(url);
 if (res=="to conditon"){  // set your condfiton
       return false
  }
 else{
  form.removeEventListener('submit', submitform, false);
  form.submit()
 }
}
```

Comment: Note that `fetchvalue()` should be `async`. There is also a relatively new `.requestSubmit()` method as well which will perform form validation (as .submit() doesn't do this), which might be useful for the OP if they can support it

Comment: @NickParsons ops, thanks for pointing that out, I didn't know about  `.requestSubmit()` it's seems better to use it in this situation